# Keyword ENTITY not allowed when creating CDS entity

Tags: abap, cds

I am trying to create CDS view entity but I get this error. "Syntax error: Keyword ENTITY not allowed"
[image]

I am trying to develop WebAPI in our S4HANA On-Premise system.
[image]

Please help with your suggestions.

Regards,
Rajkamal

Answer (score 1):

On-premise it is available [only with ABAP 7.55](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/abennews-755-abap_cds.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_2@2@), and you have 7.54, so you are out of the luck.

On S4HANA Cloud the minimum required version is 2008.

Read more in this [blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/12/16/cds-view-entity/).

Comment: Thank you for your response suncatcher.. I will confirm once the issue is resolved after upgrading the system.